# Azure AD B2C - having a user with multiple passwords / user flows

Tags: azure, authentication, passwords, azure-ad-b2c, signing

I'm currently analysis how users will get authenticated in a new application we're developing and we're looking forward to use Azure AD B2C. There is however one special scenario that I need to cover but so far I didn't get anything interesting.

**Here is the scenario:**

A user needs to authenticate in the application using **2** different ways:

1. Usual username / password
2. Barcode scanning (for username) / PIN (for password)

The second scenario is basically to be used with touch screens where the user doesn't have a physical keyboard and needs to be authenticated easily without having to type a complex password.

A single user may have to use **both ways** depending on where he works. On some workstations (PCs + keyboard), the usual username / password will be used and some others (touch screen only) they will use the barcode and PIN. Note: The barcode content will be the username.

One idea would be to duplicate the user and link them using a custom user attribute. At the signin time, we would have 2 different user flows depending on if this is a usual workstation or touch screen. However I think this is not the ideal solution since we will have to manage both users as one and that may add some management complexity.

In the end, it might sounds strange but we need to have a user with two different passwords. The password to use would depend on a specific user flow (or custom policies?).

Anyone knows if there is a build-in way to achieve this or have any other ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use two AAD B2C policies, one for the applications deployed as Kiosks, and one policy for the PC.

- One B2C policy will ask the user for username/password. Sounds like you can use a User Flow here.
- One B2C policy will ask the user to scan the barcode, insert the email into the textbox and submit the form. Then the policy will ask for the pin. This needs to be a custom policy.

You will have one user account, on this account will be the identifier, which will be the email. Add an extension attribute to hold the pin.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it makes sense. I guess the only thing is that I will have to manage to encrypt the PIN in the new attribute?Also I'm thinking about change / reset pin by a user, can I do that also by using a custom policy?

Comment: Sure, you can build all of those journeys to manage the pin too, it’s the same as password reset, except targeting an extension attribute to rewrite after verification. You can either pass the pin through your API to hash/salt/encrypt the value, or use the hashing claims transform available in the custom policy.

Comment: Great! Seems a very good way to go. I'm new to AAD B2C so I will dig deeper into what you mentioned but you pointed me into the right direction for my pin authentication. Thank you this is appreciated.